# Disable logo resizes when resolution is reduced

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a problem when creating my menu, on a wide screen, everything is fine, however when I switch to a mobile resolution, my logo is reduced little by little.

I would like to keep the same size.

```
<div className=" bg-white text-white border-b border-neutral-200">
      <div className="flex justify-around items-center align-middle lg:w-9/12 m-auto text-black  ">
        <div className=" lg:hidden w-1/5 flex justify-start">
          <MenuAlt1Icon className=" h-8 text-black hover:text-neutral-600 cursor-pointer" />
        </div>
        <ul className="relative hidden lg:flex justify-around  items-center text-center space-x-6 font-semibold hover:cursor-pointer md:order-1 ">
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">Home</li>
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">Acupuncture LotusPro</li>
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">About us</li>
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">FAQ</li>
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">Track my parcel </li>
          <li className="hover:text-neutral-600">Contact us</li>
        </ul>
        <div className="flex items-center w-1/5 lg:order-0">
          {" "}
          <Image
            src={mypic}
            alt="Picture of the author"
            width="210px"
            className="object-contain"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="flex right-0 justify-end lg:justify-evenly w-1/5 lg:order-3">
          {" "}
          <ShoppingBagIcon className="h-10 w-7 text-black hover:text-neutral-600 cursor-pointer" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Tailwind CSS but I think you can use the min-width CSS property.
Here's how to use it in Tailwind

```html
<div class="min-w-[50%]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You can use [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width) document to learn more about the mini-width of the tailwind.